# Leibniz Test: $a_n>0$

Tags: calculus

Is it necessary requirement for "Leibniz Test" that $a_n>0$ for all $n$ or it's sufficient  for number $n_0$ such that for all $n > n_0: a_n>0$.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean the test for series convergence, well, the convergence only depends on the "tail" of the series, so it is sufficient to consider the elements from $n_0$ onward.